# Can I atttach uploaded file in A&M Forms to notification email

Tags: form, plugin-amforms

I have form created with [A&M Forms plugin](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms) where the user can upload a file.
I would like to attach the file to the notification email itself.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

There is a switch in notification tab for doing that -
Add attachments with notifications / Whether to add possible attachments to the email.

Feeling stupid now :)